# C pointers in functions

Tags: c, pointers

In my c application I have the following declaration:

```
typedef double mat[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
```

I have also a global variable:

```
mat aaa;
```

in a function I want to do the following:

```
void func2(mat ccc)
{
   ccc = aaa;
}

void func1()
{
    mat bbb;
    func2(bbb);
    bbb[1][2] = 3;
}
```

I want the operations after `func2()` that I do on `bbb` to affect the global variable `aaa`, but they don't.

Any suggestions as to why the behavior is not what I expect?

Comment: Passing arrays to functions as arguments is not a good practice. They are passed as pointers and the length(s) is lost - which makes you to pass the length(s) also as argument(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `bbb` a pointer and send in the address of `bbb`.

```
void func1()
{
    mat *bbb;
    func2(&bbb);
    (*bbb)[1][2] = 3;
}
```

And edit `func2` like so:

```
void func2(mat **ccc){
    *ccc=&aaa;
}
```

Comment: Hm, as the question stands it seems like he wants the line `bbb[1][2] = 3;` somehow to affect `aaa`. Therefore, `bbb` must have a pointer type. Also, your function `func1` will not work like you expect it.

Comment: *ccc=aaa;  That won't work. Arrays cannot be copied by assignment like that.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your type `mat` isn't a pointer type, it's an array.  You can't assign to array variables in C.  The usual way to solve your problem is to use pointers:

```
void func1(void)
{
  mat *bbb = &aaa;
  (*bbb)[1][2] = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, `bbb[1][2] = 3;` will be done on `aaa`? Then you would have to do like this:

```
mat aaa;

mat* func2() {
    return &aaa;
}
void func1() {
    mat* bbb = func2();
    (*bbb)[1][2] = 3;
}
```

Comment: I edited to use the right global variable name. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conceptual error in this code - an array expression may not be the target of an assignment.  If you tried to write

```
void func1(void)
{
   mat bbb;
   bbb = aaa; 
   bbb[1][2] = 3;
}
```

the compiler would throw a diagnostic on the expression `bbb = aaa` (gcc gives an "incompatible types in assignment" diagnostic, since `aaa` is converted to a pointer type; more on that below).  What you're trying to do by passing `bbb` to `func2` is effectively the same thing, and is ultimately not going to work.

Let's get rid of the typedefs so we can see the actual types involved

```
double aaa[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
...
void func2(double (*ccc)[MAX_SIZE])
{
   ccc = aaa;
}

void func1()
{
  double bbb[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
  func2(bbb);
  bbb[1][2] = 3;
}
```

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be replaced with an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the address of the first element of the array.  When you call `func2`, the expression `bbb` is converted from type "`MAX_SIZE` array of `MAX_SIZE` array of `double`" to "pointer to `MAX_SIZE` array of `double`"; hence the declaration of `ccc` as `double (*ccc)[MAX_SIZE]`.

Similarly, in the line `ccc = aaa` in `func2`, the expression `aaa` is converted from type `double [MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]` to `double (*)[MAX_SIZE]`.

So far, `func2` is kosher, because `ccc` is a pointer expression, not an array expression, so the assignment is allowed.  `ccc` also happens to be a completely different entity from `bbb` (it receives a copy of the pointer value that `bbb` evaluates to), so writing to `ccc` has no effect on `bbb`.  If you tried to get around that by passing a pointer to `bbb`, like so:

```
void func2(double (*ccc)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE])
{
  *ccc = aaa;
}

void func1(void)
{
  double bbb[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
  func2(&bbb);
  bbb[1][2] = 3;
}
```

the compiler would throw the diagnostic on `*ccc = aaa`, either because `*ccc` has array type, or because the types of `*ccc` and `aaa` are incompatible (remember, `aaa` is converted to a *pointer* expression).